# SearchKit iterator not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, searchkit

I'm indexing CoreData entities like this:

```
func index(object: SearchIndexable) throws -> Bool {
    guard let entry = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "IndexableEntry", into: context) as? IndexableEntry else {
        return false
    }
    
    entry.key = object.key
    entry.value = object.value
    
    try context.save()
    
    let url = entry.objectID.uriRepresentation()
    
    print("URL: \(url)")
    
    guard let doc = SKDocumentCreateWithURL(url as CFURL)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
        return false
    }
    
    let text = object.indexableText.joined(separator: " ")
    
    return SKIndexAddDocumentWithText(index, doc, text as CFString, true)
}
```

Later, I need to enumerate every indexed document

```
func enumerateDocuments(_ block: (SearchQueryResult) -> Void) {
    guard let iterator = SKIndexDocumentIteratorCreate(index, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
        return
    }
    
    while let doc = SKIndexDocumentIteratorCopyNext(iterator)?.takeRetainedValue() {
        guard let url = SKDocumentCopyURL(doc)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
            continue
        }
        
        print("ENUM-URL: \(url)")
      
    /// ...
}
```

When I index 3 documents, then flush the index and try to enumerate, the resulting log output is this

```
URL: x-coredata://C12FF498-4FAA-4158-95B4-C9214FD7F85A/IndexableEntry/p1
URL: x-coredata://C12FF498-4FAA-4158-95B4-C9214FD7F85A/IndexableEntry/p2
URL: x-coredata://C12FF498-4FAA-4158-95B4-C9214FD7F85A/IndexableEntry/p3
ENUM-URL: x-coredata://C12FF498-4FAA-4158-95B4-C9214FD7F85A
```

Why does the enumerator strip the entity name and instance from the original URL?

Comment: `//C12FF498-4FAA-4158-95B4-C9214FD7F85A` is the parent doc of `IndexableEntry` which is the parent doc of `p1`, `p2` and `p3`.

Comment: I know it's the parent, but I indexed it with a complete url, not just the first path component (root). So why would an enumeration return a partial and not the complete URL?